# Undefined symbols av_register_all()

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ffmpeg

Good day,

I am beginner in Objective-C and Xcode IDE. I am trying use ffmpeg in my iOS application. I cloned https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script and build for arm64 and x86_64.

When I wanted to build app it crashed with

```
Ld /Users/nikolajpognerebko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP3-eowdhpsbeagmxydsrsscofhtuwtl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CPP3.app/CPP3 normal x86_64
cd /Volumes/sedy/xcode/CPP3
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -L/Users/nikolajpognerebko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP3-eowdhpsbeagmxydsrsscofhtuwtl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Volumes/sedy/xcode/CPP3/CPP3/ffmpeg/lib -F/Users/nikolajpognerebko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP3-eowdhpsbeagmxydsrsscofhtuwtl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/nikolajpognerebko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP3-eowdhpsbeagmxydsrsscofhtuwtl/Build/Intermediates/CPP3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CPP3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CPP3.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.1 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavutil -lswresample -lswscale -framework AVFoundation -liconv -lbz2 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nikolajpognerebko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP3-eowdhpsbeagmxydsrsscofhtuwtl/Build/Intermediates/CPP3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CPP3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CPP3_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nikolajpognerebko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CPP3-eowdhpsbeagmxydsrsscofhtuwtl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CPP3.app/CPP3

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "av_register_all()", referenced from:
      Decoder::Decoder() in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There is zipped project on OneDrive http://1drv.ms/1KkPAia because it is a best way to explain my problem.

Please help me and explain, what this problem arose.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Deprecated in ffmpeg 4.0, can  delete call - https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial/issues/29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to guess you didn't use extern "C" (like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
}
```

) around each #include statements for the ffmpeg (libavcodec/libavformat) headers? This is required in c++ code accessing c code.